# Search in many-to-many relationship with Doctrine2

Tags: php, many-to-many, doctrine-orm, symfony

This is probably an easy one but I can't figure it out nor find an answer.

I have a simple Article and ArticleTag Entities with many to many relationship. How can I get all articles with a certain tag (or tags)?

My following tries:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
    // ...
    ->andWhere('a.tags = :tag')
    ->setParameter('tag', 'mytag')
    // ...
```

or

```
    ->andWhere(':tag in a.tags')
    ->setParameter('tag', 'mytag')
```

...didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Is the many to many relationship unidirectional or bidirectional?

Comment: @Problematic: I've used the unidirectional mapping. Which would be better for my scenario?

Comment: If you use bidirectional mapping, you could add a `getArticles()` method to your tags and get the collection of articles using the tag.

Comment: @Problematic: I've thought about that too but that wouldn't be very flexible for my scenario (different types of possible filters). I've posted my final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

And the winner is ... *drumroll, please* ...

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
    // ...
    ->andWhere(':tag MEMBER OF a.tags');
    ->setParameter('tag', $tag);
    // ...
```

Thanks to everyone who has taken the time to read and think about my question!

Comment: It's work for 1 tag, but how can you get all articles by several tags?

Comment: @faost, I think you'd just need to add more *where* clauses and more parameters. `...->andWhere(':tag1 MEMBER OF a.tags')->setParameter('tag1', $tag1)->andWhere(':tag2 MEMBER OF a.tags')->setParameter('tag2', $tag2)->...;`. You could also use `setParameters` method to set all the parameters at once.

Comment: Thanks! Was just going to post exactly this question, but this worked perfectly

Comment: Also available as `$qb->expr()->isMemberOf(':tag', 'a.tags')` from Doctrine 2.5+. (https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/900b55d16afdcdeb5100d435a7166d3a425b9873/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php). Seems to be undocumented at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adаpt this example (from documentation):

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.phonenumber FROM CmsPhonenumber p WHERE p.user = u.id)');
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work in my application. Thanks anyway! I've posted my final solution as an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest using the QueryBuilder instead